# Duda relación sql

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

estoy haciendo la siguiente relación:

Un usuario se registra en un plataforma, y en función de un cuestionario se le asigna una puntuación, que a su vez le da categoría de retos, compuestos de nuevo por acciones, que debe cumplir para conseguir mejorar su puntuación.

De forma que quiero que a cada usuario se le asigne las acciones, pero solamente a ese usuario, y se pueda tener un control de si los cumple, los acepta,...

Pues no logro dar con la relación entre la tabla usuarios>retos>acciones. Tal y como esta las acciones son globales, y no especificas para cada usuario.

EN resumen la idea es que en función de la categoría del jugador se le asignen retos predefinidos, y se pueda tener un control y seguimiento.

Os pongo el esquema de la base de datos:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ecoretos CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE ecoretos (
    categoria_id integer UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    id bigserial,
    cat_nombre varchar(255)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS usuarios CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    contrasena varchar(255),
    auth_key varchar(255),
    nombre varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    apellidos varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    url_avatar varchar(255),
    direccion varchar(255),
    provincia varchar(255),
    localidad varchar(255),
    estado varchar(255),
    fecha_nac date,
    token_acti VARCHAR(255),
    rol VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'usuario',
    codigo_verificacion VARCHAR(255),
    ultima_conexion timestamp,
    fecha_alta timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    categoria_id integer REFERENCES ecoretos(categoria_id) 
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS acciones_retos CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE acciones_retos (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    titulo varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    descripcion varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    cat_id integer REFERENCES ecoretos(categoria_id),
    puntaje integer,
    fecha_aceptacion timestamp,
    fecha_culminacion timestamp,
    aceptado boolean default false,
    culminado boolean default false,
    usuario_id bigint REFERENCES usuarios(id)
);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: los nombres me confunden. los retos son una lista fija y un usuario puede tomar un subconjunto de ellos? acciones_retos sería una entidad que relaciona un usuario con N retos?

Comment: Hola, acciones-retos, si son un listado fijo  que pertenecen a una categoría (ecoretos), y un usuario tiene una categoría que se le asigna en función de una puntuación.

Pongo, un ejemplo: Un  usuario tiene una puntuación de 29 puntos, pertenece a la categoría principiante, y se le asignan los retos asociados a esa categoría.

Cada usuario debería tener sus acciones independientes, para tener el control de si acepta el reto, lo declina, y lo supera, no se si me explico bien. Gracias

Comment: para nada :( según tu comentario, tanto el usuario como los retos tienen categoría. pero es en acciones_retos donde se registra el resultado?

Comment: Los Usuarios tienen una Categoría Ecoretos que se compone de una serie de acciones (listado fijo) asociados a cada categoría. La categoría uno tiene la accion 1,2,3, la categoría 2, las acciones 4,5,6 ... Y la idea es que acciones retos tenga campos de aceptación, culminación, y la fecha en la que acepta el reto y que esten relacionados con el usuario_id.

Perdona tengo un lío importante.

Comment: puedes poner un ejemplo? No con números. Algo como :"juan es principante, los principiantes tienen los retos 'subir avatar', 'comentar un post','escribir un post'". Es algo así?

Comment: Juan tiene una puntuación de 13 puntos, lo que equivale a una categoría (ecoretos) de principiante, las acciones retos asociadas a esta categoría son:

**1. Ducharse en vez de bañarse.
2. Consumir productos mas sostenibles.
3. Utilizar las bicicleta como transporte.**

Estas acciones se le proponen al usuario, para que las realice y pueda mejorar su puntuación.

El usuario puede aceptarlas o declinarlas y si la cumple marcarla como cumplida, lo que aumentaría su puntuación.

Gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí va un intento. Existe una entidad "Categoría" que constituye una escala ascendente para identificar el "nivel" de un usuario en tramos discretos. Digamos

```
| id | nombre       |
|----|--------------|
| 1  | principiante |
| 2  | veterano     |
| 3  | experto      |
```

En un instante del tiempo, un usuario tiene una categoría (en su campo categoria_id).

En paralelo, hay una entidad "reto" que representa una tarea que el usuario debe desempeñar para ganar puntaje. Estos retos además de su propia numeración también tienen una categoría

En este ejemplo (ando con poca imaginación) vamos a decir que esto es un ecommerce, y los retos consisten en comprar un tipo de producto

```
| id | categoria_id | nombre    |
|----|--------------|-----------|
| 1  |     1        | pan       |
| 2  |     1        | agua      |
| 3  |     1        | sal       |
| 4  |     2        | carne     |
| 5  |     2        | vino      |
| 6  |     3        | reloj     |
| 7  |     3        | notebook  |
```

Usando la lógica de negocios, y conociendo la categoría de un usuario, hay que poblar una entidad `acciones` que pertenece a un usuario y corresponde a un cierto reto, teniendo además otras caracteristicas como por ejemplo el estado cumplido/no cumplido.

Puntualmente con respecto a tu pregunta, para llegar de un usuario a una acción no hay que pasar por el reto. Para llegar de un usuario a sus retos, por su parte, 
 hay dos caminos.

1. **Via la categoría del usuario**
2. **via las acciones que se le han creado**.

Lo importante es que esas relaciones **tienen significados distintos**.

- La relación entre usuario y categoría es `Usuario->belongsTo('categoria')` y `Categoria->hasMany('usuario')`.
- La relación entre reto y categoría es `Reto->belongsTo('categoria')` y `Categoria->hasMany('reto')`.

La relación entre un usuario y los retos que debiera sortear es de tipo `Muchos a Muchos`. se puede definir como `Usuario->belongsToMany('reto')` y `Reto->belongsToMany('usuario')`.

```
Usuario -> belongsTo -> Categoría -> hasMany -> Reto
```

Esta relación representa, por ejemplo:

> dado que Juan es veterano, si compra vino ganará X puntos

Y sirve para **poblar las posibles acciones** que se le ofrecen al usuario. (Poblamiento que se hace en la lógica de negocios mediante una inserción).

Luego de ese poblamiento, se genera una relación paralela entre un usuario y sus retos, pero ahora ya no dependen de la categoría.

La acción pertenece a un usuario y a un cierto reto (mediante el cual también pertenece a una categoría pero da igual).

Como la categoría de un usuario va cambiando, los retos via categoría son los retos "spot". Los retos via acciones son un historial de retos realizados y por realizar.

Fuera del momento en que la categoría spot del usuario sirve para llenar las acciones, de ahí en adelante el usuario tiene acciones sin pasar por ninguna otra entidad intermedia.

Al usar las acciones como tabla de paso en vez de las categorías, se cumple que:

- La relación entre usuario y acciones es `Usuario->hasMany('acciones')` y `Acción->belongsTo('usuario')`.
- La relación entre reto y acciones es `Reto->hasMany('acciones')` y `Acciones->belongsTo('reto')`.

(si comparas con las relaciones via Categoría, se han invertido)

La relación entre un usuario y los retos que debiera sortear sigue siendo de tipo `Muchos a Muchos`

```
 Usuario -> hasMany -> Acciones -> belongsTo -> Reto
```

Pero esa relación representa un concepto distinto. Por ejemplo:

> El día lunes Juan compró un Chateau Margaux 1929, cuyo correlativo en inventario era ZZZ. Ganó X puntos.

Y sirve para **calcular el puntaje de un usuario y posiblemente subirlo de categoría.**

Redondeando, a nivel de la capa de negocios un usuario debiera tener dos métodos

- Usuario->retosHistoricos ( Usuario hasMany Retos Through Acciones)
- Usuario->retosActuales (Usuario belongsToMany Retos Through Categoría)

Comment: Muchas gracias, una explicación muy didáctica, que me sirvió a la perfección para entender el modelado. Un saludo.